# Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', (API 17, 4.2.2)

Tags: android

When I built it on the same device last night and this morning, I had no problems at all but suddenly there was a problem.

`Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering`

Besides, I get a phrase like that.
When I look at other people's posts, I can see why.
* Update firmware
* RippleDrawable should receive Drawable instead. 
And etc. If there is any other reason, please let me know.

But I don't know how to solve it.

**Solve!!!

The fragment is static.

This was fixed in the xml file using  instead of .**

Answer (score 1):

`android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable` was added with api level 21, so it is clear why ypu get that error on api level 17. What is not clear from your post: do you use that class in your code? Are you calling `AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering`? In both cases, please show us your code.

Comment: I work with team member so... I don't know where I call hasOverlappingRendering.... Hmm.....

Comment: But thanks to your clear answer. I was confused because of reason.